# manage embed codes- link not available

Tags: powerbi

Today I published my report via "Publish to the web- embed this report for public access", just to test it via a browser.

Now I want to unpublish it (delete it from the public to view). But I can not see any links under:

setting --> manage embed codes

It only shows the one I created some months ago. Capture.PNG

Anyone knows where can I find and delete these embed code links?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you go to Manage embed codes, make sure you are in the same workspace, in which is the report you published. It will show you only those links, that are for reports in the current workspace.